# How to filter with dropdownlist, I'm lost. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a new challenge, I wanted to perform a filtering in MVC through a dropdownlist, I tried to build my controllers and views based on this site https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Filter-Data-using-DropDownList-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx, but I don't understand why using two models, and I know that the view will be different from mvc for webGrid but I can still enjoy some parts of the code right? can someone with knowledge guide me?

oh and add to this is I intend that the filtering be done by DateTime, I know that I will be stuck in this forever :)

My Model:

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_Registo { get; set; }

public List<SelectListItem> Datas { get; set; }
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string listData)
    {
        Programa model = DataModel(listData);
        return View(model);
    }

    private static Programa DataModel(string listData)
    {
        using (BaluEntities entities = new BaluEntities())
        {
            Programa model = new Programa()
            {
                
                Datas = (from c in entities.Programa
                             select new SelectListItem { Text = c.Data_Registo, Value = c.Data_Registo }).Distinct().ToList()
            };

            return model;
        }
    }
```

My View:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<form asp-controller="ShowProgramas" asp-action="Index" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="alert-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <label asp-for="ID_Programa"></label>
        <select asp-for="ID_Programa"
                class="form-control"
                asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.ListofDatas,"Value", "Text"))">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="Submit1" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

can someone advise me on a webpage or tutorial? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Controller:

```
var listSer = from d in db.Database
                      orderby d.Date
                      select d.Date;
        var servlist = listSer.Distinct();
        ViewBag.startServ = new SelectList(servlist);
```